# gcc compiler error message path cancelling parent

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I have hierarchy of files and folders containing C++ codes.
They often include each other like:

```
#include "../../Foder1/Lib4/file12.hpp"
```

When I compile the code, in case of error, I see a message like:

```
Foder2/Lib7/../../Foder1/Lib4/file12.hpp:71:4: error <something>
```

While I prefer to see `..` standing for parent directory is canceled out in the `gcc` error message:

```
Foder1/Lib4/file12.hpp:71:4: error <something>
```

Any option for calling `gcc`?

Comment: In which folder is your Makefile?

Comment: @Glapa makefile is in the root folder of the project. This path is a relative path

Answer (score 1):

If you add `-I [Folder...'s base dir]` to your gcc call you can include files by `#include "Foder1/Lib4/file12.hpp"` and then messages should be better formatted.

Comment: Recommend changing the `<>` to `""`. Read more on why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Edited.

Comment: but... we know that this files are not in the same directory so what is the point for `""`? `<>` shows us that this file is included from "external path definition".

Comment: You've got me there. Without the relative path the only reason left is stylistic: to separate external library headers and the project headers. That's an easily debatable and lost argument.